# Почему примитивные типы в JS иногда называются объектами?

Tags: javascript, объекты, методы

В некоторых туториалах по JavaScript примитивные типы данных вроде строк и чисел называются объектами, не смотря на то, что "объект" - это другой тип данных, не примитивный.

**Вот список 7 типов данных в JS:**

Шесть примитивных:

1. boolean
2. null
3. undefined
4. Числа, number.
5. Строки, string
6. символы (начиная с ECMAScript 6)

И седьмой тип данных:
7. объект (object)

При этом ряд статей называет все семь типов данных - объектами. И даёт определение методов как функций, вложенных в объекты: например, встроенный метод строки toLowerCase называют методом объекта string.

Что за путаница? Почему объект - это отдельный тип данных и одновременно данные любого типа?

Comment: Путаница от того, что авторы обучающих материалов зачастую сами недостаточно знают язык. Достоверная информация - в спецификации ECMAScript, а остальному 100%но верить не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему объект - это отдельный тип данных и одновременно данные любого типа?

Нет, все намного проще. В js есть классы для примитивных типов, которые предоставляют методы для работы с этими примитивными типами

```
// строку можно создать так
const str1 = 'string';
// или так
const str2 = new String('string');

str1 == str2; // TRUE
// Но!
str1 === str2; // FALSE
```

Тоже самое происходит, когда вы вызываете метод у примитивного типа, движок сам оборачивает вашу переменную в конструктор нужного класса, вызывает метод, и возвращает обратно примитивное значение:

```
// поэтому это
str1.toUpperCase();
// превратится, грубо говоря неявным способом самим движком, в это
new String(str1).toUpperCase();
```

Вот тут больше на английском https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067261/is-boxing-coercion-in-javascript

Comment: «это ... превратится в это ...» - нет, не превратится. Последнее выражение вернет `object`, а не `string`. Вероятно, стоит добавить в это выражение вызов `.valueOf()`.

Comment: @yar85 Давайте проверим `typeof new String('eqrewr').toUpperCase();`, выведет  `string`. А вот просто `new String(str1);` вернет объект, но это проделывает движок, неявным способом, поэтому все ок

Comment: А, точно, моя ошибка - не учел что метод `toUpperCase()` в конце выполнения вызывает ту же внутреннюю функцию, что и `valueOf()`.

Comment: Ничего он не оборачивает ещё начиная с ES5.